# Login fails via Stack Exchange OpenID

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-openid

I tried to log in several times just now (via the StackExchange OpenID service), but my login attempt failed.  I got an error message like this:

"An error occurred on the server

This event has been recorded.

If you believe you encountered this message in error, please report it."

(with `https://openid.stackexchange.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/openid/provider` showing in the address bar, and with "please report it" a link going here)

After retrying multiple times I was eventually able to log in successfully.  So, I don't know if this is a transient issue or not, and I don't know if I can reproduce it -- but I thought I'd report it in case it is helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the whole Sandy-induced NY -> OR data center failover, I can't recall exactly what issue would have been affecting you but I'm pretty confident it was temporary and has been fixed.

OpenID logins should be functioning normally for everyone.

Comment: A similar error occurs again: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/179625/205264