# StackExchange OpenID problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-exchange-openid

I tried logging in with stackexchange on the Programmers site, and got this error:

[image]

I have cookies and so enabled. The error page told me to file a report, so here you are. The troubleshooting info:

[image]

Logging in on meta stack overflow doesn't work either, using stackexchange OpenID:

[image]

Comment: maybe reset your cookies and try again

Comment: @phpNoOb thanks, lol, I couldn't login anymore, now using facebook for OpenID. I'm adding another debug picture!

Comment: I had this problem also.

Comment: IIRC some issues like this have been encountered by people whose IPs change frequently. Do you know if yours does?

Comment: @JeremyBanks thanks, but no, never (I also checked for this time)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We had a spurt of odd connection issues between our web servers and the redis instance openid.stackexchange.com uses, which was causing a lot of legitimate XSRF tokens to get rejected.

It's been fixed, you should be able to login using Stack Exchange OpenIDs now.

Comment: Thank you, I just noticed it worked again.